Questions about a differential geometry exercise
The exercise comes from an old exam from the 90s at my university
Let $\varphi(u,v) = (v^2-u,u,u-v) \quad u,v \in \mathbb{R^2} \quad S=im(\varphi)$
a) Prove that $S$ is a regular surface and that a single line contained in the surface passes through each point of $S$.
b) Show that the kernel at each point of $S$ of the Weingarten operator is the
subspace generated by the vector $(−1, 1, 1)$.
c) Find the lines of curvature of $S$.
d) Show that the intersection of $S$ with the plane $x = y + z$ is the trace of a
geodesic.
e) Show that the field $\boldsymbol{t} + \boldsymbol{b}$ is a field of parallel vectors along
the curve from the previous section
$\mathbf{\text{My attempt}}$
$\mathbf{a)}$
From $\varphi$ we get
$$
y = u \Rightarrow z = y-v \Rightarrow x = (y-z)^2-y
$$
Now, if we consider
$$
F(x,y,z) = x+y-(y-z)^2
$$
$F$ is differentiable and $\\ \nabla F(x,y,z)=(1,1-2(y-z),2(y-z)) \ne (0,0,0) \Rightarrow$ $S$ is a regular surface
For the second part I don't know how to proceed
$\mathbf{b)}$
$$
\varphi_u = (-1,1,1) \\ \\
\varphi_v = (2v,0,-1)
$$
Therefore the coefficients of the first fundamental form are:
$$
E = \langle\varphi_u,\varphi_u\rangle = 3, \\ \\ 
F = \langle\varphi_u,\varphi_v\rangle = -2v -1, \\ \\
G = \langle\varphi_v,\varphi_v\rangle = 4v^2+1
$$
The coefficients of the second fundamental form that I have obtained are
$$
e = 0, \\ \\ f = 0, \\ \\ g = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-4v+8v^2}} 
$$
So the Weingarten operator is given by
$$
-\mathrm{I}^{-1}*\mathrm{II} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \frac{2v+1}{\sqrt{2}(4v^2-2v+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\\ 0 & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}(4v^2-2v+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\end{pmatrix}
$$
Given $v \in T_pS \Rightarrow v = \lambda\varphi_u+\mu\varphi_v$.  Since $dN_pS: T_pS \mapsto T_pS$ the kernel should be the vectors of $T_pS$ that verify:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2v \\\ 1 & 0 \\\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & \frac{2v+1}{\sqrt{2}(4v^2-2v+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\\ 0 & \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}(4v^2-2v+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \mu = 0 \Rightarrow v = \lambda\varphi_u = \lambda(-1,1,1)
$$
$\mathbf{c)}$
Curvature lines are solutions of the equation $\begin{vmatrix}(u')^2 & -u'v' & (v')^2\\\ E & F & G\\\ e & f & g\end{vmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{vmatrix}(u')^2 & -u'v' & (v')^2\\\ 3 & -2v-1 & 4v^2+1\\\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-4v+8v^2}}\end{vmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow -\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-4v+8v^2}}[(-2v-1)(u')^2-3u'v']=0$
From here I got that $u = const$ and $v = -\frac{1}{2}$ are lines of curvature.
$\mathbf{d)}$
I know what a geodesic is, but I cant get the equation of the curve $S \cap x=y+z$ and therefore check if it verifies the geodesic equations. Is my approach correct?
$\mathbf{e)}$
It would be enough to check that the parallel field equations are verified
Any hints, suggestions or even corrections would be appreciated.

For c) remember that principal directions are orthogonal at non-umbilic points. For d) and e) you can certainly easily get a parametric equation for this curve.

Thanks @TedShifrin! May I have another hint for d)? Since it's an old exam, I didn't do anything like that in my course. btw your text on differential geometry helped me a lot :)

Use the equation of the plane to relate solve for $u$ in terms of $v$.

Thank you so much @TedShifrin! I think I got it, is it $(u(t),v(t)) = (\frac{t^2+t}{3},t) $ right? Now I can finish the exercise :)
